# "И действительно ли — дарить человеку цветы..." Уместно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

"И действительно ли — дарить человеку цветы — это достойный поступок?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предложение нуждается в редактировании (вариант зависит от смысла вопроса):

(1) **И действительно,  дарить человеку цветы — это достойный поступок?**

Многие сомневаются в правильности такого подарка.

(2) **И дарить человеку цветы — это действительно достойный поступок?**

Как оценить такой поступок?